# Problema con campo que contiene valor 0 (cero)

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario con un campo ***estado*** que permite escoger entre dos valores **0** y **1**.
Si se selecciona 1 entra al *if*. `["estado"]=> string(1) "1"`

```
if (isset($_POST['estado']) && !empty($_POST['estado']) ) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}
```

Pero si se selecciona 0. No entra al if. `["estado"]=> string(1) "0"`.
Qué tengo que modificar para que entre al *if* ?

Comment: Debes tener claro que estás evaluando, si valores o booleanos... los booleanos pueden leerse como 1 y 0, pero se interpretan como true o false... 1 es true, 0 es false...

Comment: El campo es `tinyint(1) Unsigned` no es booleano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en que empty devuelve FALSE si el valor es 0
(https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php), tal vez puedas cambiar el if por algo como esto:

```php
if (isset($_POST['estado']) && ($_POST['estado'] == '0' || $_POST['estado'] == '1')) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si los datos vienen de un formulario, los campos tipo input `<type="text" ...>` o `<select ...>` siempre traen un valor, aunque no se escriba nada o no se seleccione nada, por lo que `isset` siempre será `true` en esos casos.

Donde si se debe hacer la comprobación es en campos tipo checkbox `<input type="checkbox" ...>`

Un formulario simple de ejemplo:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="var1"><br />
    <select name="var2">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="0">Opcion 1</option>
        <option value="1">Opcion 2</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="var3" value="10">Seleccionado 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="var4" value="11" checked>Seleccionado 2<br />
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

Si no se escribe ni se selecciona nada y se hace un SUBMIT, `var_dump($_POST)` tendrá el siguiente valor:

```
array(3) { "var1"=>"", "var2"=>"", "var4"=>"11" }
```

Como ves, hace falta `var3`, porque es un checkbox, así que no tiene mucho sentido el `isset` en los demás campos.
Por otro lado [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) devuelve `true` si la variable existe y su valor es diferente de `0`, y esa es la razón por la que no está entrando al `if`.

Entonces, debes hacer una comparación estricta: `if($_POST['estado'] !== '')` porque `0 == false` y `'' == false` dan `true`. En caso de que no haya una tercera opción vacía, entonces no se necesita nada porque si o si se seleccionará uno de los 2 valores. O también puedes usar `<select name="var2" required>` para obligar a seleccionar una de las 2 opciones con valores.

**[ !NOTA ]** Todo lo que he dicho se invalida si los campos pueden tener el atributo `disabled`, o que el DOM pueda ser controlado por Javascript.

Comment: En el formulario el campo estado es `<select ...>` pero si no se escoge nada, no se envía nada.

Comment: El `select` siempre tiene un campo default pre-escogido, aunque esté sin el atributo `value="xyz"`, incluso enviando un `<option></option>` a secas, el resultado en `var_dump()` es `["var2"] =>string(0) ""`. O sea, siempre un `select` va resultar en `true` en `isset()`. Para mejor control puedes colocarlo como lo puse en el ejemplo. De esa forma soporta el atributo `required`.